# res.headersSend in Node.js for the default error handling?

Tags: node.js, error-handling

I am learning Node.js and defualt error handling part.
Here is my code.

```
app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
//   if (res.headersSent) {
//     return next(error);
//   }
    res.status(error.code || 500);
    res.json({ message: error.message || "An unknown error occurred!" });
});
```

I am not sure why do I have to return next(error) when headers has been already sent.
I commented the if (res.headersSent) ... part out and the error handling middleware still works as it should.

Can anyone help me understant what the part is for?